# How does nltk.pos_tag() work?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

How does `nltk.pos_tag()` work? Does it involve any corpus use? I found a source code (`nltk.tag` - NLTK 3.0 documentation) and it says

```
_POS_TAGGER = 'taggers/maxent_treebank_pos_tagger/english.pickle'.
```

Loading _POS_TAGGER gives an object:

```
nltk.tag.sequential.ClassifierBasedPOSTagger
```

, which seems to have no training from corpus. The tagging is incorrect when I use a few adjective in series before a noun (e.g. *the quick brown fox*). I wonder if I can improve the result by using better tagging method or somehow training with better corpus. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 20):

According to [the source code](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag.html), `pos_tag` uses NLTK's currently reccomended POS tagger, which is `PerceptronTagger` as of 2018.

[Here is the documentation](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#nltk.tag.perceptron.PerceptronTagger) for `PerceptronTagger` and [here is the source code](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag/perceptron.html#PerceptronTagger).

To use the tagger you can simply call `pos_tag(tokens)`. This will call `PerceptronTagger`'s default constructor, which uses a "pretrained" model. This is a pickled model that NLTK distributes, file located at: `taggers/averaged_perceptron_tagger/averaged_perceptron_tagger.pickle`. This is trained and tested on the Wall Street Journal corpus.

Alternatively, you can instantiate a `PerceptronTagger` and train its model yourself by providing tagged examples, e.g.:

```
tagger = PerceptronTagger(load=False) # don't load existing model
tagger.train([[('today','NN'),('is','VBZ'),('good','JJ'),('day','NN')],
[('yes','NNS'),('it','PRP'),('beautiful','JJ')]])
```

The documentation links to [this blog post](https://explosion.ai/blog/part-of-speech-pos-tagger-in-python) which does a good job of describing the theory.

TL;DR: `PerceptronTagger` is a *greedy averaged perceptron* tagger. This basically means that it has a dictionary of weights associated with features, which it uses to predict the correct tag for a given set of features. During training, the tagger guesses a tag and adjusts weights according to whether or not the guess was correct. "Averaged" means the weight adjustments are averaged over the number of iterations.

Answer (score 7):

The tagger is a machine-learning tagger that has been trained and saved for you. No tagger is perfect, but if you want optimal performance you shouldn't try to roll your own. Look around for state-of-the art taggers that are free to download and use, such as the Stanford tagger, for which the NLTK provides an interface.

For the Stanford tagger in particular, see `help(nltk.tag.stanford)`. You'll need to download the Stanford tools yourself from http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It involves the corpora named Penn Tree Bank which defines syntactic and semantic information,a bank of linguistic trees.